# What memory adress are we referencing to when we use a const reference to an rvalue

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue

Consider the follwoing code:

```
int main() 
{
    const int& number=10;
    cout << number << endl << &number << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As output I get:

```
10
0x62ff08
```

As far as I know "10" is an rvalue without memory adress, so where does the memory adress come from?

Comment: The compiler creates a temporary object for you.  The address is that of the temporary.

Comment: What's the differnce then between this temporary object and a regular `int`?

Comment: You can't do anything to the temporary as it's const.  But if that's what you want you still don't need a reference as you can just do `const int foo = 10;` to get a constant int.

Comment: `10` does not have a memory address.  `number` has a memory address.

Comment: Ok so when intializing to an rvalue it makes no difference if we use `const int` or `const int&`? @NathanOliver

Comment: It makes no difference in this case.  Really since C++17 it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you wrote:

```
//------------------vv---->10 is a prvalue and temporary materialization will result in an xvalue
const int& number = 10;
```

**temporary materialization** happens as can be seen from [temporary materilization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> Temporary materialization occurs in the following situations:
>
> - when binding a reference to a prvalue;

Now `number` refers to the materialized temporary(xvalue).

Moreover the lifetime of the temporary is extended as can be seen from [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime)

> The **lifetime of a temporary object may be extended by binding to a const lvalue reference** or to an rvalue reference (since C++11), see reference initialization for details.

Comment: But why call it temporary? SInce it is the same as a `const int`?

Comment: @tempdevnova `10` is a prvalue and temporary materialization will result in an xvalue. Next, `number` will be bound to that resulting `xvalue`. We use the term "temporary" here **because a temporary has been materialized**.

Comment: *But why call it temporary?*  Because it is a **temporary**. *SInce it is the same as a `const int`?*  It is **not** the same as a `const int`.  You can use it the same way as a `const int`, and likely the compiler will compile it to the same exact machine code.